# How to enable multi-touch gestures on surface pro 7

Tags: linux, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro, gestures

I've installed libinput gestures but when I run `sudo libinput debug-events` I do not see any pinch events. How do I enable them on ubuntu Gnome.

I am on a surface pro 7 and have verified that "IPTS Touch" is the touch screen (when I disable it with `xinput disable "IPTS Touch"` the touch screen stops working).

Output of `xinput --list-props "IPTS Touch"`:

```
Device 'IPTS Touch':
    Device Enabled (176):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (178): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix (333):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (334):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (298): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (299):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (300):    0, 0
    Device Node (301):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (302):    1118, 2463
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux Surface-Pro-7 5.13.13-surface #1 SMP Fri Sep 3 00:16:33 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [linux-surface repo](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix), multi-touch is not supported on the surface pro 7.

Lesson learned, RTFM.